# New user on newly created server, added to sudo group but still no sudo access

Tags: server, sudo, users

I created a new server (ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01) with Ubuntu 22.04 and added a new user (`michael`). I then added the user to the `sudo` group. When I check the groups for `michael` I see the correct groups.

```
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01:/srv/users/michael# groups michael
michael : michael sudo sp-sysusers
```

**But every time I try to run a sudo command I get the same message:**

```
michael@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01:~$ sudo cd /
You must SSH in as root to run this command: sudo cd /
```

I checked `/etc/passwd` to ensure the user was added right

```
michael:x:1000:1000::/srv/users/michael:/bin/bash
```

I checked `/etc/sudoers` and all looks correct

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I've restarted the machine multiple times. Logged off `michael` and even tried `pkill -STOP -u michael` but still no luck upon reboot. I've been at this for hours running in circles. What am I missing?

Comment: You can't run `sudo cd`  because `cd` is a shell built-in. Try to run some other command, for example `sudo fdisk` or `sudo parted`.

Comment: @sudodus same thing:
michael@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01:~$ sudo parted
You must SSH in as root to run this command: sudo parted

Comment: *"created a new server"* how exactly? The message `You must SSH in as root to run this command` looks like something implemented by a VPS provider.

Comment: @MichaelGoodin you are using ssh with a none-admin user. Oh and you can not use sudo using the root account either; if you want an admin account add "michael" (name in the command prompt)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue but I'm still not sure why it worked. I used serverpilot.io to install the server framework AND to add the user `michael`. I then used `sudo` to change `michael`'s privileges. It never worked until I removed `michael` and readded using `sudo` instead of serverpilot.io.

My guess is that `michael` was added to another group, that I was ignoring, which caused it not to have true sudo priv's.

Moral of the story, don't use serverpilot.io to create admin-level users.